# FollowUp help/advice needed ---Java BankAccount app - reuse variable in cases through switch statement

Tags: java, variables, switch-statement, case

Follow up question, need help with case 5 - using this code and joptionpane to display output. How would I call objects from the arraylist(database =db/deleted) in meaningful results? I am able to display the ref to the object. I was reading about overloading tostring method but I am not sure if I am in the right direction?? Any help or advice is appreciated!! Thanks in advance.

P.S. as a side note, should I delete my previous questions once they are answered or just leave them on the board?

```
    package bankaccount;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BankAccountTest 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Database db = new Database();
    Database deleted = new Database();
    boolean done = false;
    while (!done)

    {
        int activity = IO.getInt("Please choose one of the following:"+
         "\n 1 to create new account"+ "\n 2 to delete an account"+
        "\n 3 to withdraw from an account"+"\n 4 to deposit to an account"+
         "\n 5 to list all customers"+"\n 6 to list all deleted customers"+
         "\n 7 to display single account "+"\n 8 to exit this program");

    switch(activity)
    {

  case 1:

  //Create new account
  String LastName = IO.getString("Please type last name: ");
  String FirstName = IO.getString("Please type first name: ");
  Name n = new Name (LastName,FirstName);

  //Create address object
  String street = IO.getString("Please type your address: ");
  String city = IO.getString("Please type your city: ");
  String state = IO.getString("Please type your state: ");
  String zipcode = IO.getString("Please type your zipcode: ");
  Address addr = new Address (street,city,state,zipcode);
/*        //Create Account number
  Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2000000000);
  AccountNum accno = new AccountNum(randomInt);
*/     //Create customer object
  String accno = IO.getString("Please enter the account number: ");
  Customer c = new Customer(n,addr,accno);
        //Create bankaccount object 
 double amt = IO.getDouble("Please type the opening account balance: ");
  BankAccount b = new BankAccount(c, amt);
  db.add(b);
  break;


  case 2:

  // Delete an account / copy account info to deleted database
   String key = IO.getString("Enter account number to delete: ");
       db.search(key); 
     if (db.inlist())
  {
        deleted.add(db.remove(db.getindex()));
  } else 
  {
   //Display not found
    IO.notFound();
  }
  break;


  case 3:

  // withdraw from an account
    key = IO.getString("Enter account number to withdraw from: ");
    db.search(key);
   if (db.inlist())
  {
     double amount = IO.getDouble("Enter an amount to withdraw : ");
     b.withdraw(amount);
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Current balance is: "+b.balance);

  } else 
     {
         IO.notFound();
     }
  break;
```

Case 5:

```
  //Display single account
  if(db.list.isEmpty())
  { 
    String s = "The list is empty";
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(s, 6, 20);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane,
                "Current Customers", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < db.list.size(); i++)
  {
   // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " "+db.list.size());  
    String s = "These exists in the list: ";
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(s, 6, 20);
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text); 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pane,
                "Current Customers List", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }
  break;


  case 8:

  // exit program
      done=true;
      break;

 default:
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid choice, please choose again ", 
                                "ERROR",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
   }           
  }
  }
```

classes

```
package bankaccount;

public class BankAccount 
{
Customer cust;
double balance;

BankAccount (Customer c,double b)     
   {
        cust = c;
     balance = b;
   }

 void deposit (double amt)
   {
     balance = balance + amt;
   }

 void withdraw (double amt)
   {
     balance = balance - amt;
   }

 double getbalance ()
   {
    return balance;
   }

 Customer getcustomer ()
   {
    return cust;
   }
    }
```

&

```
package bankaccount;

public class Customer 
{
 Name name;
 Address addr;
 String accno;

 Customer (Name n, Address addy, String acc)
 {
     name = n;
     addr = addy;
     accno = acc;
 }

 Name getname()
 {
     return name;
 }

 Address getAddress()
 {
     return addr;
 }

 String getAccountNumber()
 {
     return accno;
 }

 void changeAccountNumber(String acc)
 {
     accno = acc;
 }
 }
```

&

```
package bankaccount;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Database 
{
    int index;
    boolean found;
    ArrayList<BankAccount> list;
    BankAccount acc;

Database()
{
 list = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
}

void add(BankAccount b)
{
   list.add(b);
}

BankAccount remove (int i)
{
    return list.remove(i);
}

 BankAccount getaccount()
{
    return acc;
}

ArrayList getlist()
{
    return list;
}

int getindex()
{
    return index;
}

boolean inlist()
{
    return found;
}

void search (String key)
{
    found = false;
    int i = 0;
    //int.length = list.size();

    while (i < list.size() && !found)
    { BankAccount b = list.get(i);
       if (key.equals(b.getcustomer().accno))
  {
  acc = b; found = true; index = i;
  }
else
  {
  i++;
  }
    }
}
}
```

&

```
package bankaccount;

public class Address 
{
 String street;
 String city;
 String state;
 String zipcode;     

  Address (String str, String cty, String st, String zip)
 {
     street = str;
     city = cty;
     state = st;
     zipcode = zip;
 }

 static String getstreet(String street)
 {
     return street;
 }

 public String getcity()
 {
     return city;
 } 

 public String getstate()
 {
     return state;
 }

 public String getzip()
 {
     return zipcode;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the variable outside the switch clause because otherwise it cannot be defined in case 3.

**Edit**

Try the following:

```
db.getaccount().withdraw(amount);
```

instead of:

```
b.withdraw(amount);
```

By this line, you get the Account from the database and edit it there.

Comment: Got it - but this code requires variables/input from case 1 to define that object b

Comment: Why don't you make this object b a property of the class?

Comment: Im new , ill look into that, not sure what that means. Can you give a quick code example?

Comment: Thank you!  Perfect ,, worked... I verified using joptionpane to display.   I couldnt figure that part out!!!

Comment: Follow up question - using this code and joptionpane to display output. How would I call objects from the arraylist(database =db/deleted) in meaningful results? I am able to display the ref to the object. I was reading about overloading tostring method but I am not sure if I am in the right direction??